# Error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) it is always showing when i go to cconsole

Tags: html, css

I'm encountering an error in my web application where I'm seeing the message "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" in the browser console. This error seems to indicate that a resource (like an image, script, or stylesheet) is being requested by my application but is not found on the server.

I've checked my code and confirmed that the resource path is correct, but I'm still facing this issue. How can I troubleshoot and resolve this error?

Here are some additional details:

The URL of the resource causing the error: [Insert URL here]
The steps I've already taken to troubleshoot the issue: [Describe any steps you've already tried, such as checking the resource path, verifying server configurations, etc.]
Any relevant code snippets or configurations: [Include any relevant code snippets or configurations related to the resource loading]
Any assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Make sure to replace [Insert URL here] with the actual URL of the resource causing the error, and provide as much relevant information as possible to help others assist you effectively.

i am getting this error when i simpy run my html code so can you fix this error => Error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="10.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, molestias
      ab. Vero cumque veritatis architecto ullam non recusandae possimus
      excepturi molestias perferendis, doloremque debitis consectetur amet eum
      itaque aperiam sint quam optio.
    </h1>
    <br /><br />
    <button>CLICKED</button>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="text" placeholder="NAME" />
    <br /><br />
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
h1:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgb(26, 17, 17);
}
button:active {
  background-color: rgb(0, 30, 255);
  color: rgb(255, 25, 0);
}
input:focus {
  color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
  background-color: rgb(12, 21, 21);
}
```